# Filtering from phoenix when loading a table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-phoenix

I would like to know how this exactly works,

```
df = sqlContext.read \
          .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
          .option("table", "TABLE") \
          .option("zkUrl", "10.0.0.11:2181:/hbase-unsecure") \
          .load()
```

if this is loading the whole table or it will delay the loading to know if a filtering will be applied.

In the first case, how is the way to tell phoenix to filter the table before loading in the spark dataframe?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is not loaded until you execute an action which requires it. All filter applied in the middle:

```
df.where($"foo" === "bar").count
```

will be pushed down by Spark if it is possible. You can watch results of predicate pushdown by running `explain()`

Comment: I know it for other kind of loads, but I can not put a filter  before the load now :S. (I am with pyspark and phoenix)

Comment: @PabloCastilla If you write `spark.(..).load().where(...).count`, then Spark will automatically do predicate pushdown. You don't have to deal with it

Comment: You are totally correct. I have seen that with the explain() function.

Thanks!

Comment: explain() function show below：*(1) Filter (isnotnull(UPDATED_AT#68) && (UPDATED_AT#68 > 2019-04-23 00:00:00))+- *(1) Scan PhoenixRelation.....          PushedFilters:.....