# Incremental and parallelism read from RDBMS in Spark using JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sqoop

I'm working on a project that involves reading data from RDBMS using JDBC and I succeeded reading the data. This is something I will be doing fairly constantly, weekly. So I've been trying to come up with a way to ensure that after the initial read, subsequent ones should only pull updated records instead of pulling the entire data from the table. 
I can do this with sqoop incremental import by specifying the three parameters `(--check-column, --incremental last-modified/append` and `--last-value)`. However, I dont want to use sqoop for this. Is there a way I can replicate same in Spark with Scala?

Secondly, some of the tables do not have unique column which can be used as `partitionColumn`, so I thought of using a row-number function to add a unique column to these table and then get the `MIN` and `MAX` of the unique column as `lowerBound` and `upperBound` respectively. My challenge now is how to dynamically parse these values into the read statement like below:

```
val queryNum = "select a1.*, row_number() over (order by sales) as row_nums from (select * from schema.table) a1"

val df = spark.read.format("jdbc").
option("driver", driver).
option("url",url ).
option("partitionColumn",row_nums).
option("lowerBound", min(row_nums)).
option("upperBound", max(row_nums)).
option("numPartitions", some value).
option("fetchsize",some value).
option("dbtable", queryNum).
option("user", user).
option("password",password).
load()
```

I know the above code is not right and might be missing a whole lot of processes but I guess it'll give a general overview of what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

It's surprisingly complicated to handle incremental JDBC reads in Spark. IMHO, it severely limits the ease of building many applications and may not be worth your trouble if Sqoop is doing the job.

However, it is doable. See this thread for an example using the dbtable option:

[Apache Spark selects all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323635/apache-spark-selects-all-rows)

To keep this job idempotent, you'll need to read in the max row of your prior output either directly from loading all data files or via a log file that you write out each time. If your data files are massive you may need to use the log file, if smaller you could potentially load.